# Maximal order of elements of $\textrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

In the case of $\textrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, I know that the order of any finite order matrix in this group is at most $6$. This follows from the fact that $\textrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \textrm{Mod}(S_{1})$, the mapping class group of the torus. Furthermore, finite order elements of the mapping class group of a surface have order at most $4g + 2$ by a theorem of [Wang](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/242993380_Maximum_orders_of_periodic_maps_on_closed_surfaces). This bound is also attained, for example in this case by the matrix {{1, -1}, {1, 0}}. I would like to know if similar bounds hold when $n > 2$, that is:

> What is the maximal order of a finite order matrix in $\textrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ when $n > 2$?

Comment: Regarding the finite order elements of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$, there are elementary proofs using only the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the following result (Landau's estimate):

*Proposition* Let $G(n)$ be the maximal order of a torsion element in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Then 
$$
\log G(n)\sim (n\log(n))^{1/2}.
$$
For a proof see [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/JofAlgebra98.pdf).
For example $G(2)=G(3)=6$, $G(6)=30$, or $G(12)=210$.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** the $\phi$'s in the lcm were out of place, and there is a slight caveat in that I'm not sure the companion matrices for the cyclotomic polynomials have positive determinant, it depends on the constant coefficient of $\Phi_m$, so this formula works for $\mathrm{GL}$. It's also exactly the same formula and reasoning as in the article Dietrich Burde links to.

---

Take a finite order matrix $g$ in $\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb Z)$. It is diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$, and its complex eigenvalues are roots of unity. Its minimal polynomial $\mu$ is a unitary polynomial with rational coefficients and divides the characteristic polynomial, which is a polynomial with integer coefficients, hence $\mu$ actually has integer coefficients and is a product of distinct cyclotomic polynomials (because of its roots and having integer coefficients).

Each cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m$ is the minimal polynomial of its companion matrix $C_m\in\mathrm{SL}(\phi(m),\Bbb Z)$, which is integer valued and has finite order (because of diagonalisable with roots of unity as roots) equal to $\phi(m)$. You can create a matrix $\in\mathrm{SL}(n,\Bbb Z)$ as a bloc matrix using companion matrices, so the answer to the question ought to be

$$\max_{k_1,\dots,k_r\text{ s.t. }\phi(k_1)+\dots+\phi(k_r)\leq n}\,\mathrm{lcm}(k_1,\dots,k_r)$$

One could carry out the calculations for small $n$.

Comment: Does this work in the n=2 case? The characteristic polynomial of the matrix {{1, -1}, {1, 0}} (which has order 6) is $\Phi_1 \Phi_1$ so it looks to me like you've just shown that this matrix has order at most 1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MarkBell I think so, because $\phi(6)=2$, so $C_6\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\Bbb Z)$ will do the job. The only thing I'm not sure about is wheter all the companion matrices are in SL rather than in GL...

Comment: @MarkBell This is the same idea as G. Lewitt uses by the way to obtain his $G$ function. I see though that I made a mistake as there shouldn't be any $\phi$'s in the lowest common multiple part.

Comment: @MarkBell I know this comment is 6 years old, so you’re probably not interested anymore (this is mostly for future readers), but the characteristic polynomial of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&&-1\\1&&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is $t^2 - t + 1 = \Phi_6$, not $\Phi_1 \Phi_1 = t^2 - 2t + t$.

Comment: For $\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb Z)$ one needs slight adjustments: For example, the only ($1 \times 1$) matrix with determinant $1$ is $(1)$ (which has order $1$), but $(-1) \in \operatorname{GL}(1, \mathbb{Z})$ has order $2$. Luckily, we can read off the determinant from the characteristic polynomial: If you use the convention that it is monic, you need a constant term of $1$ for $n$ even and a constant term of $-1$ for odd $n$. The only cyclotomic polynomial with constant term $-1$ is $\Phi_1$, all others have constant term $1$.

Comment: Hence, one can find some additional conditions on the $k_i$ that ensure that a matrix with the right minimal polynomial and the right determinant exists. (For example, for odd $n$, one of the $k_i$ needs to be $1$.)